# Plotting a chart showing which values in a range exist in a group of lists

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, charts, visualization

I have a dataset consisting of financial stock IDs [0, 1400] and timestamps [0, 1800]. For a given ID, it either does or does not have data for a given timestamp.

I have created a dictionary where each key is an ID, and each value is a list of all the timestamps for which that ID has data.

I would now like to plot a chart with the each row corresponding to an ID, and each column corresponding to a timestamp. Each cell `[i, j]` of the chart will be coloured green if ID `i` has data for timestamp `j` (`if j in dict[i]`), and red if not.

Here is a sample I produced manually in Excel:

[image]

Can this be done through matplotlip or some other library?

Since the chart would be of size 1400x1800, the cells can be very small. I am attempting to reorder the data so that the number of green cells intersecting between adjacent IDs is maximised and so this chart will allow me to provide visualisations of how well I have achieved these overlaps/intersections across the dataset.

To provide some data,  I simply iterated through the first 20 IDs in my dictionary and printed out the ID and the list of its timestamps. [each line is in the form of `ID [list of IDs timestamps]`](https://pastebin.com/qKNyHdwz)

**EDIT:**

Here is my first attempt on a example of data on a small scale. Although, this does achieved what I set out to do, it is a very brute force solution, so any recommendations on improvements would be appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

TSs = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ID_TS = {0: [1, 2, 3], 1: [2, 3, 4, 5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(index=ID_TS.keys(), columns=TSs)

for ID, TS in ID_TS.items():
    bools = []
    for i in TSs:
        if i in TS:
            bools.append(True)
        else:
            bools.append(False)
    df.loc[ID] = bools

plt.imshow(df, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: The dataset is huge and conatins a whole lot more than just the IDs and timestamps, so that is a bit difficult. I could print out and provide the first 20 IDs and their corresponding lists of timestamps?

Comment: Yeah, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Added sample data to my post

Comment: read up on MCVE's. you posted an image, not a working example of your data and code

Comment: To answer your question directly, yes it can be done. Set the index on the timestamp and ID of your values, unstack on the ID, pass that result through `pandas.isnull`, then plot as an image

Comment: @PaulH I am failing to understand what you mean by "set the index on the timestamp and ID of your values"? I have added sample data to my question

Comment: it's difficult  to explain in any more detail without an MCVE

Comment: @PaulH I don't have any code to provide. All I have done so far is read my dataset, created the ID-timestamp dict and now would like to plot what I have explained, but I don't even know where to start as I am very unfamiliar with matplotlib - I don't even know what type of plot I should use. I don't think I can provide anything other than a visualisation of what I would like to achieve, and a sample of the data  I am using to achieve this.

Comment: Well, the code that reads in the data would be a start, right? At the moment there is a very long ascii file without any explanation how to interprete it. I would also for now suggest to forget about matplotlib, and try to produce a pandas dataframe or a numpy array from your data. Once that is done, come back to worry about plotting.

Comment: @PaulH I have come to a solution similar to what I understand you first trying to explain, but it is very brute-force and doesn't utilise much functionality from pandas. I would appreciate your tips before I attempt to implement this on the far more massive dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to generate your dataframe doesn't work. So I took some liberties with that...

```
import numpy
import pandas
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib import ticker

TSs = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ID_TS = {0: [1, 2, 3, numpy.nan], 1: [2, 3, 4, 5]}

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()

img = ( 
    pandas.DataFrame(data=ID_TS, columns=TSs)
        .isnull()
        .pipe(numpy.bitwise_not)
        .pipe(ax.pcolor, cmap='RdYlGn', edgecolors='k')
)

unit_ints = ticker.MultipleLocator(1)

ax.set_xlabel('Time')
ax.set_ylabel('ID')
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(unit_ints)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(unit_ints)
```

[image]

Comment: The code from the question works fine and produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f54el.png). (There are two IDs and 6 times). Whatever your code is doing, it is not actually answering the question I'd say.